# Background Image XY offset Not Keyframeable?

Tags: animation

Is the Background Image xy offset in Camera properties Not keyframeable? or do i just need to assign them to a keying set or something along these lines?

now, when i hover the mouse and hit "i" i get:

"Failed to resolve path to property, try manually specifying this using a Keying Set instead"

if so, can someone point me to a tutorial for how to add these parameters to a keying set? 
i attempted to do this but failed.

thanks for help!

Comment: Probably you misunderstood the message, you can't keyframe this parameter. You can add a Background Empty, set child of the camera and animate its location.

Comment: @FFeller thank you!